# Save Custom Timestamp with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I want to save my timestamp in following format with TypeORM on NestJS

Date formats should be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+01:00 or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sss+01:00

Answer (score 0):

If you use `new Date()` you will get the same format you mention above. You can also use the package [moment,js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.